# Project Management templates - Official standards across industry

Tags: documentation, artifacts, templates

Does anyone know if, according to PMI, or any other PM certification, there are official templates for project management artifacts.

I am interested in the following documentation:

- Project charter
- Functional specifications
- Non-functional specifications
- RACI matrix
- Highlevel technical requirements

I have found various templates online, however I am not sure if there are any officially standardized templates that could be adopted on a PMO level?

Can anyone recommend a PM professional site, which provides such artifacts or a book where such can be found?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure what an "official" template would mean.   "Official" implies governance & authority. PMI doesn't have the authority to govern my organization.   I'm not sure that project risk would be reduced by selecting a template from an an external organization in preference to a template created by my organization's PMO. (And quite frankly, I have enough trouble getting managers to sign off on our organization's forms.  If they had to sign a form created by an external organization, they'd probably never do it.)

Comment: Across which industry?  PM is a practice across multiple industries.  I've had a lot of trouble getting stakeholders from two different bureaus to agree on the best template, let alone across two different industry segments.  IMHO such a standard would be so general as to be worthless.  I'd also push back on principle against such an effort.  The point of PM is to close a project by influencing participants and stakeholders.  Trying to satisfy an external standards body would make it tougher to actually manage the project.

Answer (score 1):

Before going any further, you may want to check with your organizations PMO to see if they have the project management templates that you have outlined in your question.

Although there isn't an official template repository, www.projectmanagement.com which is powered by the PMI, does offer the sample templates you are looking to use.   You must be a member to download these templates.

As an alternative, there are plenty of free templates that are available on the internet.  For example, the US government has many of the types of templates that you are looking for; the CDC has a very good project charter that you can download @ https://www2a.cdc.gov/cdcup/library/templates/CDC_UP_Project_Charter_Template.doc
You may want to look at www.smartsheet.com as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The PMI website endorses/links to the templates on projectmanagement.com ... https://www.projectmanagement.com/Templates/index.cfm